# Need help setting height to fit browser window

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm coding a simple website using html, tables and css, but I'm having some trouble with something I've normally been able to do - set the height to fit the browser window.

I have a container `<div>` that is housing all the elements, so I'm not sure why it isn't working. I've done this before when the site only had one image as its background and it worked fine.

Here is a demo of the site: http://december2nd.ca/redi/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you improve your question? Here are some guidelines http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please add an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve illustrating your problem to your post. Don't just throw a link to a site.

Answer (score 0):

It actually works fine, if you reset margin and padding.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Now you will have to reposition elements like the navigation.

```
nav {
    top: 30px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

(I actually just added px to your values, it didn't really work before.)

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for your reply to my question! I added the reset to my css file but don't see any changes - the content is still not fitting to the height, did I do something wrong?

I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Okay, now I get your question. Well, you can add `height: 100%;` to some elements like #maintable, the table in your first td etc. etc., but then your pictures aren't big enough to fill 100% of the pages height. Additional information: The tables in your second td for example both should have a height of 50%, since there are two elements, which share the full height of 100%. I honestly wouldn't code it the way you did, you shouldn't use tables if it's not a table.